# WebDav Performance - Drive mapping vs Web Browsing

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, webdav, dfs-r, iis-8.5, namespaces

I can't seem to find any information about this topic. We have setup an IIS server with WebDav support and this seems to be a fine solution but we're getting fairly slow performance out of a specific folder. Although this folder has about 2600 items in it when I browse to it in a browser it's near instant, but if I map a drive using net use and try to open it, it takes a very long time (roughly 60 seconds).

I've tried turning off Automatically Detect Settings in IE and this doesn't help. I'm not sure where to continue troubleshooting this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT** - It seems to be an issue when connecting to a DFS share on a remote server as I connected the drives to the IIS server and the lag is considerably less. Is there any reason connecting in IIS via a namespace share would cause this lag?